# Авторизацию на Web-ресурсе через SSL пользовательские сертификаты?

Tags: ssl

Поделитесь опытом внедрения пользовательских SSL сертификатов для авторизации на сайте?

P.S. Кроме WebMoney это кто-то вообще сделал?

Comment: Насколько я представляю себе SSL они не для авторизации на сайте. SSL это криптографический протокол между клиентом и сервером, базовым для этого протокола является сертификат. На основании данного сертификата данные шифруются, поэтому непосредственно к сайту это не имеет никакого отношения. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: WebMoney в интерфейсе Light используется сертификат пользователя на сколько мне известно.

Comment: Да, вам правильно изветсно. Это достаточно удобно. К сожалению, не имею опыта реализации такой штуки, но знаю, что такой способ авторизации вполне стандартен и можно почитать литературу по сабжу, связанную с используемыми вами технологиями. Как правило, авторизацию с помощью сертификатов поддерживается на уровне веб-сервера.

Comment: А что меня в данном случае интересует, а как распространяются сертификаты персональные?

Comment: Ну сертификаты, как уже было указано в ответе - они не ssl, а x.509. Удостоверяют подлинность сервера (при необходимости клиента) путём проверки тех, кто сертификат подписал (цепочки подписантов). Есть ряд организаций/сайтов, которые (за денежку) могут вам его подписать и вы сможете предоставлять свой сертификат (как правило своего сайта клиентам) для проверки.

Answer (score 1):

Если на php, то есть функция

```
openssl_x509_parse()
```

Сам же сертификат находится где-то в $_SERVER